# Cloud Foundry Stylized Error Pages

Tags: cloud-foundry

Just wondering as RTFM'd and I still couldn't find it. Is it possible to set an external URL whenever a CF application responds to bad gateway or any 50x errors? In Heroku, they have an environment variable called ERROR_PAGE_URL which you can point an external URL that their router will redirect to.

Can this be done in CloudFoundry as well instead of the generic and unfriendly error page?

Comment: do you host your own Cloud Foundry instance? As a user of CF you can't customize the design of HTTP codes.

Comment: Ahh, that explains it then thanks. The CF instance is deployed on internal servers and I'm just a user.